# node_modules/angular2-qrscanner/angular2-qrscanner.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbo

Tags: typescript, npm, angular-cli, ng-build

We get Metadata error which is hindering our deployments. As it does not allow ng build. Below is the configuration ; followed by full error trace.

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module <Angular4.3-AppPath>/node_modules/angular2-qrscanner/angular2-qrscanner.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol <Module_Name>in <Angular4.3-AppPath>/src/app/modules/manage/device/device.module.ts, resolving symbol <Module_Name>in <Angular4.3-AppPath>/src/app/<Module_Path>.ts
at syntaxError (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1725:34)
at simplifyInContext (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24953:23)
at StaticReflector.simplify (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24965:13)
at StaticReflector.annotations (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24395:41)
at _getNgModuleMetadata (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
at <Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
at Array.reduce ()
at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:241:66)
at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (<Angular4.3-AppPath>\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:495:24)
at
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

> webpack: Failed to compile.

setting:angular2-qrscanner version: 1.0.7 Angular CLI: 1.5.0 Node: 8.10.0 OS: win32 x64 Angular: 4.3.2 ... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router @angular/animations: 4.4.0-RC.0 @angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10 @angular/cli: 1.5.0 @angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8 @angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33 @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20 @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35 @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0 @ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0 @schematics/angular: 0.1.3 typescript: 2.6.1 webpack: 3.8.1

Comment: Please use the [edit] link. Don't post things in comments.

Comment: Resolved in localhost:4200. Deprecated the package to angular2-qrscanner@0.1.7. And it works !!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in localhost:4200. Deprecated the package to angular2-qrscanner@0.1.7. And it works !!

However on hosting as a Azure WebApp, the camera refuses to load. It gives the error message on Console of Chrome as below:-

Refused to load media from 'blob:/5c07044f-447c-45a9-979e-458d5e955f8f' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'unsafe-inline' data: https:". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Resolution working on:-
Edge and IE do not give this error. Camera opens but does not scan. Should I switch to another QR scanner or do I continue with "angular2-qrscanner". I am contemplating the same.